# Layout with css float no shifting when resizing the container division

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, css-float

I want to describe my idea first, check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/As7Hz/6/):

There are two divs, #left and #right, #left has a fixed width and both are floated left. Container division has no fixed width and can be resized in my design. The requirement is that #right cannot be shifted to next line. Width of #right will be automatically adjusted to the container division and overflow text will be hidden. All of the three divisions have fixed height.

In the fiddle mentioned above, I set #right 50% width to make it adjusted, which is not that perfect. The container division may not be full and shifting problem still occurs.

I can implement the layout with javascript to adjust the width of #right, but is there any css solution with the help of min-width or anything else?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you want it to be??

http://jsfiddle.net/N3jhV/

Please dont hesitate to correct me

Comment: I don't think so, the container division can be resized and has no fixed width.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8sBkz/4/ here is my solution, thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/4qLmq/

This solution will work only if the `#left` element has fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ? http://jsfiddle.net/As7Hz/14/

Answer (score 0):

How about this version: http://jsfiddle.net/As7Hz/18/